# I have to convert an multi-dimensional array to a simple array which can be used by leafletjs

Tags: php, sql, arrays, multidimensional-array, leaflet

I am getting trouble while converting an array received from mysqli_fetch_all() function to an array of array which can be used with leaflet js

---

[This is the array i am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QXD4m.jpg)

[This is the array i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iiJlH.jpg)

Comment: Post your code/attempt, example data, expected result from that data and what currently happens (we need details, incl. full error messages, if any.) Also read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You should also [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) that was recommended to you when you registered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without being able to see any code you may have, I'd guess your array in php looks like

```
$myArray = array(array('x1', 'x2'), array('y1', 'y2'));
```

What you need to do is json_encode it and it will be accessible to your javascript:

```
<?php $myArray = json_encode($myArray); ?>
<script> var myArray = <?= $myArray ?>; </script>
```